# When can a runtime exception occur during commit?

Tags: oracle, transaction, exception

I've been asked this question but neither I seem to be able to answer it on my own, nor can I find anything related on the web. So what are the cases that might cause a runtime exception when committing a transaction in Oracle?The only thing that I can think of is the low disk space. Are there any other?

Comment: I've seen it also with a Materialized View with refresh on commit.

Comment: can you confirm what you mean by a runtime exception?

Comment: By that, I mean an error that prevents commit.

Comment: or it could me one of the thousands of ORA-600, ORA-700 or ORA-7445 or ORA-4031 etc etc. it can be anything. Real question is why would someone want to know? because no matter what you account for, there could be something else that could go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question to [Oracle community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3963699) and the answer was deferred constraints.